# Writing my own shell in C -- stuck on user input during "sleep"

Tags: c, shell, sleep

I'm just about wrapped up writing a shell in C and I have run into one problem, which doesn't cause the shell to stop functioning, but it does bug me.

The shell is written using fork() and exec() and everything works perfectly. However, when the user sends a "sleep 5" command, I'm having an issue.

For example:

```
    $ smallsh
     : sleep 5



      (user presses enter 4 times during sleep)
     :::: (sleep is now done)
```

The prompt (:) will print all on the same line if a user presses enter at all during the sleep command. I'm not sure how to handle this so any ideas would be great.

Here is the (condensed) main:

```
    #define MAX_LENGTH 2048
    int main()
    {
        char input[MAX_LENGTH];
        char **commands;
        do {   
          printf(": ");
          fgets(input, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
          commands = parseCommand(input); //parser not included here
          if (strcmp(input, "\n") == 0) {
              ; //do nothing 
          } else {
              executeCommand(commands); 
          }
        } while (1);
        return 0;
     }

     //condensed executeCommand
     int executeCommand(char **args)
     {
         pid_t pid;
         int status;

         pid = fork();
         if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
         } else if (pid == 0) {
            execvp(args[0], args);
            perror("execvp");
            exit(1);
         } else {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
         }
        return 1;
     }
```

sleep will correctly go through execvp and work functionally just fine--it just queues up the : and prints them all on the same line. If I add a \n right before the prompt (printf("\n: ")) it makes the output look very silly. Is there an elegant way to fix this issue? Thanks. ahead of time.

Comment: This is why other shells echo the input in this situation.

Comment: one might consider seperation of concerns.   Make the input async, which feeds a queue.  Then have a processing loop that takes one command out of the queue and executes it.

Comment: @EvilTeach Sounds like exactly what the OS does for you...

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after `printf(": ");` and, if necessary, `putchar('\n');` instead of your `// do nothing` line.

Comment: putchar('\n'); did the trick. Thanks!